# Portable Anti-virus/spyware/malware toolkit

Tags: windows, anti-virus, portable-apps

I am trying to remove a plethora of viruses from a friend's computer and was wondering if anyone knew of a portable anti-virus toolkit?

What I am thinking of is a live-cd/dvd that may boot up windows or linux that had a few anti-virus tools on there.  Right now I'm booted into safe mode and running some scans but the viruses have actually loaded in safe mode and are preventing a lot of my scans.

I've got an extra Mac and an extra Desktop to get the tools, but I do not want to mount the infected drive in my clean systems.

So does anyone know of a good toolkit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Avira AntiVir Rescue System](http://www.free-av.com/en/tools/12/avira_antivir_rescue_system.html) is an excellent Linux-based bootable CD that allows you to scan for infections, rescue data, and repair other damaged parts of the system. It is very frequently updated, and best of all, it's free.

> Avira AntiVir Rescue System is a
>   Linux-based application that allows
>   accessing computers that cannot be
>   booted anymore. Thus it is possible
>   to:
>
> - repair a damaged system,
> - rescue data,
> - scan the system for virus infections.
>
> Just double-click on the rescue system
>   package to burn it to a CD/DVD. You
>   can then use this CD/DVD to boot your
>   computer.
>
> The Avira AntiVir Rescue System is
>   **updated several times a day** so that
>   the most recent security updates are
>   always available.

[image]

Comment: +1 - I like my answer, but Avira feels more like a professional solution... although, "scan for games" and "Scan for joke programs"... are there any examples, sounds rather weird!?

Comment: The software is designed to eliminate any malicious tools or unwanted software. Some people may consider games unwanted software if somebody else installed it on their system. Joke programs aren't necessarily malware, just the kind of annoying tools that open your disc tray or turn your monitor on and off and such.

Comment: +1 Makes sense! However, I understand joke programs being bad but it seems weird to have games in the same category as spyware and dialers. Oh well! - the program still works well and I guess that is all that matters for the question!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [Ultimate Boot CD for Windows](http://www.ubcd4win.com/index.htm), it has quite a few tools built in for dealing with a variety of malware.

### Anti-Spyware Tools

```
aSquared Free
AVG AntiSpyware
CWShredder
EzPCFix
HiJackThis
Rootkitty
Spy Bot
Super AntiSpyware
WinSock Fix
```

### AntiVirus Tools

```
AVPersonal
Avast! Tool
Kaspersky VRT
McAfee Stinger
```

Comment: +1 Contain multiple (advanced) tools and we could add it almost any other. e.g. avira antivir http://www.wieldraaijer.nl/bartpe/

Comment: Your link is dead, redirects to advertisements instead. Is this what you mean: http://www.ubcd4win.org/ ?

Answer (score 1):

**[A-Squared Command Line Scanner](http://www.emsisoft.com/en/software/cmd/)** is a portable virus and malware scanner and removal tool. It includes all functions of the Anti-Malware scanner and both the top scan engines (Emsisoft Anti-Malware and Ikarus Antivirus).

[image]

The pros: it is the extremely fast, it is most efficient as it also scans for malware which is usually not covered by typical anti-virus software. The cons: there aren't really any, unless you're not comfy with the command line :)

If you prefer a GUI, there's also a [portable version](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/clamwin_portable) of **[ClamWin](http://www.clamwin.com/)** available.

[image]

However, ClamWin does not remove or quarantine any infected files, you will have to delete/rename the files manually and it only scans for viruses, not malware.

Comment: The ClamWin image does not appear to be showing up.

Answer (score 0):

**Kaspersky Virus Removal Tool**
Kaspersky Virus Removal Tool is a portable app designed to scan and disinfect an infected computer from viruses and other types of malicious programs.
*General functions:*

- Automatic and manual removal of viruses, Trojans, and worms.
- Automatic and manual removal of Spyware and Adware modules.
- Automatic and manual removal of all types of rootkits

you can download it from [here](http://support.kaspersky.com/viruses/kvrt2015)